# Bottom view stick in bigger screen size and move scrollable in small screen size

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

Have a look at this image carefully. As you know in android different devices have different screen density and size. Sometime we keep many ui scrollable to support small size screens.

Following is my requirement.
In this ui there is a small at the bottom which is sticked and there is card somewhere in middle of the screen.

For bigger devices where i am able to see this card i should show the bottom view sticked to the botttom.

for smaller devices in which card can't be fit (acually card is large/long it has lot many content/information)  in the same screen, the bottom view would be beneath the card and obviously it would be hiddden, once we scroll the screen up the view will come out from bottom(see in second image).

Help how can i achieve this

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show what you have tried so far?

Comment: have you tried aligning the bottom view to the bottom of parent.
In second screenshot, the card is overlapping with status bar, have you tried constraining your view to a guideline?